# Sorting a list of lists in Common Lisp

Tags: list, sorting, character, common-lisp, alphabetical-sort

I'm trying to write some function to sort this type of list:

`((1 A) (2 E) (4 D))`

I found the built-in function sort in Common Lisp, but I can't do what I want.
This should be the result:

```
'((1 A) (4 D) (2 E))
```

I want to sort the list by the second element of each lists, alphabetically.

This is what I've done:

```
(sort '((1 A) (4 D) (2 E)) #'char-lessp :key #'second)
```

Anyway, I would understand how to sort a list with a specific function, using :key'.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use:

```
(sort '((1 A) (4 E) (2 D)) #'string<= :key #'second)
```

The reason is that `char-lessp` compares characters, and `A`, `E` and `D` are not characters, but symbols. The function `string<` can used to compare their names, which are the *strings* `"A"`, `"E"` and `"D"`. For instance:

```
CL-USER> (string= 'symbol "SYMBOL")
T
CL-USER> (symbol-name 'symbol)
"SYMBOL"
```

Note that the comparison operators on strings have two versions, for case sensitive and case insensitive comparisons:

```
CL-USER> (string= "a" "A")
NIL
CL-USER> (string-equal "a" "A")
T
CL-USER> (string= 'a "a")
NIL
CL-USER> (string-equal 'a "a")
T
```